# Is it safe to resize Tor Browser window with JavaScript disabled completely?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, fingerprinting

Recent Tor Browsers (as of writing, current stable version is 3.6.5) resize the browser window to a multiple of 200x100 pixels on opening. I understand this is to reduce the chances of a user being fingerprinted by their screen size. Unfortunately with a widescreen laptop and using a desktop environment with both top and bottom panels this results in a tiny Tor Browser window that is uncomfortable to use.

Websites like  EFF's Panopticlick (https://panopticlick.eff.org) that measure screen size fail to display a measurement when JavaScript is turned off. When searching I can't seem to find any non-JavaScript method to measure a user's browser/screen size.

Is it safe to resize the Tor Browser window, as long as JavaScript is disabled globally beforehand?

Answer (score 4):

CSS can also measure your window width and height and send it back to the server. See the demo here:
https://arthuredelstein.github.io/tordemos/media-query-fingerprint.html