# Tor Browser windows' size when Safest security level?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Why does the yellow banner 'Maximizing Tor Browser can allow websites to determine you monitor size, which can be used to track you...' show up even when the security level is 'Safest' in Tor Browser? This disables javascript, and as a consequence panopticlick.eff.org suggests the size of my monitor cannot be determined.

Comment: This has already been asked before [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/is-it-safe-to-resize-tor-browser-window-with-javascript-disabled-completely?rq=1)

Comment: Please flag such questions as duplicates. Thanks.